# eBay Finding API in Java throws 'IllegalArgumentException: Not supported: indent-number' exception

Tags: java, exception, illegalargumentexception, ebay-api

I'm playing around with the eBay Finding API for Java, and executing a basic test search based on the tutorial included. The call completes, but a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` exception is thrown during execution.

Here's the basic code adapted from the example:

```java
ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
config.setEndPointAddress("http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1");
config.setGlobalId("EBAY-GB");
config.setApplicationId("my app id");

FindingServicePortType serviceClient =FindingServiceClientFactory.getServiceClient(config);

FindItemsByKeywordsRequest request = new FindItemsByKeywordsRequest();
request.setKeywords("HTC One X");

FindItemsByKeywordsResponse result = serviceClient.findItemsByKeywords(request);

System.out.println("Ack = "+result.getAck());
```

And here's the logged output:

```
[ERROR] 2012-11-01 16:52:09,847
fail to get xml string from SOAP message

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not supported: indent-number
```

Has anyone else experienced this/have any idea why?

Comment: Would help if you told us which line throws the  `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` and included the stacktrace.

Comment: @jschoen i got the same problem,but no idea about it

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it's bug in JAXWSHandler. Try to disable request/response logging with

```
config.setSoapMessageLoggingEnabled(false);
```